# I was trying to build a webhook with OAuth login flow. but I am stuck with the below-stated problem

Tags: facebook, message-queue, amazon-elb, facebook-webhooks

I am building a webhook app but I have a problem, I have a load balancer and the problem is like, let's say:
FB is sending me msg to my WEBHOOK, and after some processing, I am moving those to a common rabbitMQ, but the problem arises when I have more than one machine deployed on the same URL via load-balancer.

E.G.:
FB sent me 3 msg on WEBHOOK m1, m2 & m3,
i have load-balancer added to 3 machines mc1, mc2 & mc3,
now since I have load balancer then when FB sends me msg then chances are that all the messages get to different machines...
like let's say m1 -> mc1
m2 -> mc2
m3 -> mc3
and now for some reason when I was putting the data in the queue there is an order mismatch.. like mc3 puts data first then mc2 then mc1.. so now the order of msgs in the queue is m3, m2, m1.
now order got distorted, how do I manage the order?